# Python Grahics from Linux CLI

Tags: python, linux

I am anticipating the answer to be no, but I wanted to verify. If I write a Python program that was a GUI, can I launch that from a Linux CLI and still get the GUI? I am trying to build an embedded Linux system and I want to exclude everything that isn't necessary. This is a kiosk-like device, so all I need is my Python GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Various widget toolkits (GTK+, Qt, etc.) can run on [DirectFB](http://directfb.org/) instead of X11, which will allow you to have a GUI running on the Linux framebuffer device instead of requiring a full X server.

Answer (score 0):

To run GUI anything on Linux you'll need an [X server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) at a minimum.

There are curses based sorta-GUI libraries that assume an 80x24 character terminal emulator if you want to go that route, but you'll still need some kind of display.